# Django - Save to disk a pdf file generated using xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/) which helped me in generating pdf files in Django using xhtml2pdf. Now what I want is to save the generated file to disk without having to prompt the user to download the file.

Below is the code I am using to generate the pdf file in utils.py file and views.py file.

```
#utils.py file

from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):

    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None 

#views.py snippet of code

html = template.render(context)
pdf = render_to_pdf('tdn.html', context)
if pdf: 
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    filename = "TDN_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
    content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
    download = request.GET.get("download")
    if download:
        content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
    TDN.objects.filter(id=tdn_no).update(printed=1)
    return response

return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

Any pointers on how I can write to disk the generated pdf will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want to save the file on client computer? You can't force it: it depends on browser settings (and I do not think any browser would allow that)

Comment: @Dona I want to save it on the server, not the client machine.

Answer (score 3):

Tried this?

```
with open('mypdf.pdf', 'wb+') as output:
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), output)
```

If you want to save it to ImageField use `ContentFile` in Django!

Comment: Thanks @KshitijSaxena for the suggestion. I do that in the view or the utils file?

Comment: You can do it inside the `if not pdf.err` block! It is suggested to create a new function and pass `pdf` as a parameter. Call that function inside the if block!

Comment: Getting an error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'pisaContext'

Comment: You can refer this answer for this error:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900067/7697652

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try that out

Comment: Thank you so much Kshitij. It worked fine now after using that link you referred me to. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @TonyCarter Please select it as the correct answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: What helped was the answer on the link you gave in the comments. Please update your answer to reflect that before I select it as the correct answer.